# How to optimize datetime comparisons in mysql in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

### CONTEXT

I have a large table full of "documents" that are updated by outside sources. When I notice the updates are more recent than my last touchpoint I need to address these documents. I'm having some serious performance issues though.

### EXAMPLE CODE

```
select count(*) from documents;
```

> gets me back 212,494,397 documents in 1 min 15.24 sec.

```
select count(*) from documents where COALESCE( updated_at > last_indexed_at, TRUE);
```

> which is apx the actual query gets me 55,988,860 in 14 min 36.23 sec.

```
select count(*) from documents where COALESCE( updated_at > last_indexed_at, TRUE) limit 1;
```

> notably takes about 15 minutes as well. (this was surprising to me)

### THE PROBLEM

> How do I perform the `updated_at > last_indexed_at` in a more
> reasonable time?

### DETAILS

I'm pretty certain that my query is, in some way, not sargable. Unfortunately, I can't find what about this query prevents it from being executed on a row independent basis.

```
select count(*) 
from documents 
where last_indexed_at is null or updated_at > last_indexed_at;
```

doesn't do any better.

nor does

```
select count( distinct( id ) ) 
from documents 
where last_indexed_at is null or updated_at > last_indexed_at limit 1;
```

nor does

```
select count( distinct( id ) ) 
from documents limit 1;
```

### EDIT: FOLLOW UP REQUESTED DATA

This question only involves one table (thankfully) in a rails project, so we conveniently have the rails definition for the table.

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `document_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `document_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `allowed_ids` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fields` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `last_indexed_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_documents_on_document_type` (`document_type`),
  KEY `index_documents_on_locale` (`locale`),
  KEY `index_documents_on_last_indexed_at` (`last_indexed_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

`SELECT VERSION();` got me `5.7.27-30-log`

And probably most import,

```
explain select count(*) from documents where COALESCE( updated_at > last_indexed_at, TRUE);
```

gets me exactly

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | documents | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 208793754 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: What does `explain select count(*) from documents;` shows? In fact what does each explain shows ? Post `show create table documents ` in the question, too.

Comment: You could run `EXPLAIN select count(*) from documents USE INDEX (PRIMARY)` and see what's happen

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us your MySql version. Also, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) and [edit] your question to tell us more about your table and query plan.

Comment: Are there any additional clarification I could add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! MySQL 5.7 introduced [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) — which gives us a way of indexing expressions!

If you do something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE documents
  ADD COLUMN dirty BOOL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(updated_at > last_indexed_at, TRUE)) STORED,
  ADD INDEX index_documents_on_dirty(dirty);
```

...and change the query to:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM documents WHERE dirty;
```

...what results do you get?

Hopefully, we're moving the work of evaluating `COALESCE(updated_at > last_indexed_at, TRUE)` from **Read** time to **Write** time.

Answer (score 2):

**Add a *covering* INDEX**

If you had `INDEX(last_indexed_at, updated_at)`, the 15-minute queries might run somewhat faster.  (The order of the columns does not matter *in this case*.)

Assuming both of those columns are columns in the table.  If so, then the query *must* read every row.  (I don't know if the term "sargable" covers this situation.)

The `INDEX` I suggest will be faster because it is "covering".  By reading only the index, there is less I/O.

The repeated 15 minutes is probably because `innodb_buffer_pool_size` was not big enough to hold the entire table.  So, it was I/O-bound.  My `INDEX` will be smaller, hence (hopefully) small enough to fit in the buffer_pool.  So, it will be faster, and even faster on the second run.

**Slow OR**

`OR` is usually a terrible slowdown.  But I don't think it matters here.

If you were to initialize `last_indexed_at` to some old date (say, '2000-01-01'), you could get rid of the `COALESCE` or `OR`.

Another way to clean it up is

```
SELECT  SUM(last_indexed_at IS NULL) +
        SUM(updated_at > last_indexed_at) AS "Need indexing"
    FROM t;
```

I still need the index.  `SUM(boolean expression)` sees the expression as 0 (false or NULL) or 1 (TRUE).

Meanwhile, I don't think the `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` is any different than `COUNT(*)`.  And the pair of `SUMs` should also give you the value.

Again, I am depending on "covering" being the trick.

**"More than .." trick**

In some situation, you don't really need the exact number, especially if it is "more than some threshold".

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE ... LIMIT 1000,1;
```

If it comes back with "1", there are at least 1000 rows.  If it comes back empty (no row returned), then not.

That will still have to touch up to 1000 rows (hopefully in an index), but that is better than touching a million.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you're on a recent MySQL version (5.7+), add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) to your table containing your search expression, then index that column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE t 
 ADD COLUMN needs_indexing TINYINT 
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
     (CASE WHEN last_indexed_at IS NULL THEN 1
           WHEN updated_at > last_indexed_at THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END) VIRTUAL;
ALTER TABLE t 
  ADD INDEX needs_indexing (needs_indexing);
```

This uses drive space for the index, but not in your table.

Then you can do `SELECT SUM(needs_indexing) FROM t` to get the number of items matching your criterion.

But: you don't have to count all the items to know you need to reindex some items. Doing a `COUNT(*)` on a large InnoDB table is very expensive as you have discovered. You can do this:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE needs_indexing = 1) something_needs_indexing;
```

You'll get 1 or 0 from this query very quickly. 1 means you have at least one row meeting your criteria.

And, of course, your indexing job can do

```sql
SELECT * FROM t WHERE needs_indexing=1 LIMIT 1;
```

or whatever makes sense. That will also be fast.